# Calculate Total Time Value in Hours & Minutes

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an input form where the user will input their start time and their start time. I then have a function that calculates the time difference and stores the hours and minutes worked in a new field.

What I want to do is calculate the total time as one value in Hours and Minutes.

The following SQL will bring all the meta_value stored in the database

```
SELECT wp_frm_item_metas.meta_value
FROM wp_frm_item_metas
WHERE 1=1 
   AND wp_frm_item_metas.field_id = '103'
```

This returns values as follows (first 5 only)

meta_value

```
2:15
1:15
2:15
4:15
0.00
```

If I use the following

```
SELECT SUM(wp_frm_item_metas.meta_value) AS total_hours
FROM wp_frm_item_metas
WHERE 1=1 
   AND wp_frm_item_metas.field_id = '103'
```

I do not get the total in hours and minutes so I wonder if anyone could help me to achieve this please?

Thanks

Wayne

Comment: When I've done this I've just stored total minutes (ie I hours * 60 + minutes and stored that value in the database). Is that an option for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TIME_TO_SEC to convert to seconds, then SUM. For output you could use SEC_TO_TIME function to get hours:mins. E.g:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(wp_frm_item_metas.meta_value))) AS total_hours
   FROM wp_frm_item_metas
WHERE 1=1 
   AND wp_frm_item_metas.field_id = '103'
```

I haven't tested the above but should get you close...

Comment: If I wanted to extend this further to take account of the date that the hours were worked which is stored under wp_frm_item_metas.meta_value WHERE wp_frm_item_metas.field_id = '84' to only calculate the hours from the above within the last 1 month using something like `WHERE date > DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)` How could I integrate that please? Thanks Wayne

Comment: I have tried `SELECT TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(wp_frm_item_metas.meta_value))),'%H:%i' ) AS total_hours
   FROM wp_frm_item_metas
WHERE 1=1 
   AND wp_frm_item_metas.field_id = '103'
   AND DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)` but that does not work and has no effect on the result - it still outputs the total hours overall.